# Why does Eset Smart Security 5 not allow me to access localhost?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, nod32

I am trying to access my apache server through my web server via localhost. With my Eset smart security 5 disabled, I can access it no problem. With the firewall enabled I cannot access it.

I didn't have this problem with ESS4, does anyone know what I would have to change to add an exception for localhost?

I tried adding 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' to  Advanced setup->web and email->web access protection->URL address management->list of addresses excluded from filtering - but the problem still exists

Typing both localhost and 127.0.0.1 into my browser causes the connection to fail (this is the only fix i found through google, and it doesn't work)

Thanks!